# Search For Vendors in BuddyPress Multivendor Site

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, buddypress, vendor

I'm looking for a way to create a search box on a multi-vendor WooCommerce site. The theme, Flatsome, has a search in the header for products, but my client would also like to have a search by vendor. We have installed BuddyPress and BP WC Vendors plugins. I tried the BP Profile Search, but the users of the site are customers and vendors, and I couldn't see a way to restrict the search to vendors. Thoughts?

Comment: Have you seen the Store Locator demo on the WC Vendors demo site? It can search vendors by product category.  http://dev.wcvendors.com/store-locator/

Answer (score 0):

Try the GeoDirectory plugin and the GeoDirectory Buddypress add-on. This will solve your problem and all your vendors to create a vendor profile. It will also allow your users to become vendors, and it comes with a sidebar widget to search for vendors.